# Incrementing nested arrays - with date information

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I have three integer arrays. SIZE is 365.

```
double month[SIZE], day[SIZE];
int countMonths[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

In the Month array i want to populate the int value of the month - for the first 31 fields will have a 1, the next 28 fields will have a 2, etc. For the amount of days in that month.

month[0-31] will have the value 1 (corresponding to month 1)
month[32-60] will be the value 2 (corresponding to month 2)

My loop is not working. The outer loop will cycle through the 365 items in the array. I wanted the inner loop to cycle the amount of - corresponding to the values in countMonths[1] etc. ;

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j < countMonths[j]; j++)
        month[i] = i+1;
```

The second query what I would like to do is using the same countMonths inner loop just have the update instead of putting all the values 1 (corresponding month 1). It will put 1, 2, 3 etc. until it gets to 31 and then start at 1 again.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j < countMonths[j]; j++)
        day[i] = j;
```

Neither query is doing what I want to do ... please advise. 
Using the below logic I seem to update and cycle through the first of each month.

```
int i = 0;
int currentmonth = 0;
int currentday = 1;
while(i < SIZE &&  i < countMonths[currentmonth])
{
    month[i] = currentmonth+1;
    day[i] = currentday;
    i++;
    currentday++;

if(currentday > countMonths[currentmonth]);
   {
    currentmonth++;
    currentday = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: If the indexes for month two are inclusive, 32 to 60 is *29* days, which doesn't happen every year.

Comment: That is okay - its only to pull/update data for 2013 (not a leap year).

Comment: As for your problem, you will go out of bounds of `countMonths` in the inner loop. And a couple of hints for a possible solution: You don't need to loop from zero to `SIZE` at all, and the outer loop should be over `countMonths`.

Comment: yes, i know something isn't correct. That is why i posted it here for help. I basically need to have two arrays (months and days) that will have corresponding data. so that i can say use an index and say what month and what date it is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you mention not to loop from zero to Size. to set the outterloop to go from 0 to and cycle throught each countMonth value. please let me know what suggestion you have because i tried a few options and none of them seem to make logical sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 2 indexes with 2 loops, when it would be more useful to use 3 indexes in 1 loop:

```
currentDay = currentMonth = 1
while(destinationIndex and currentMonth are valid indexes)
    assign current day and month to destination arrays
    increment destinationIndex and currentDay
    if(currentDay is greater than possible for currentMonth)
        increment currentMonth
        set currentDay back to 1
```

Comment: you think it would make sense to use a while loop rather then a for loop that goes from day 1 to day 365 (and in some capacity link month/day arrays to populate necessary values.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Either of `while` or `for` will do. Just make sure you don't access `month`, `day` or `countMonths` arrays out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks. @user694733. Sorry a bit of confusion on my part what is the destination index - are we looking at months[i] and days[i] and when we review what currentMonth is a valid index (we just look at i in that case -so its less then 12)?

Comment: @YelizavetaYR My `destinationIndex` is the same as your `i`. And yes, `currentMonth-1` should be less than 12, if you use range `1..12` for `currentMonth`.

Comment: Ok. i'm going to think about it to see if i can come up with a solution.

Comment: when i try like this `int i = 0;
    int currentmonth = 0;
    int currentday = 1;
    while(i < SIZE &&  i < countMonths[currentmonth])
    {
        month[i] = currentmonth+1;
        day[i] = currentday;
        i++;
        currentday++;
    
    if(currentday > countMonths[currentmonth]);
       {
        currentmonth++;
        currentday = 1;
       }
    } ` I some how get the first of every month to populate and that's it. (the first 12 dates are the first of each month)

Comment: @YelizavetaYR The `while` condition `&& i < countMonths[currentmonth]` makes loop stop too soon; It should be `&& currentMonth < 12`.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Also, `if` condition has one `;` before `{` which shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
int dayInYear = 0;

for (int month = 0; month < 12; ++month)
{
    for (int dayInMonth = 0; dayInMonth < countMonths[month]; ++dayInMonth)
    {
        month[dayInYear] = dayInYear + 1;
        ++dayInYear;
    }
}
```

Very similar to your the original (non-working) solution in the question, but still quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#include "assert.h"
```

And later

```
    double month[SIZE], day[SIZE];
    int countMonths[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    int iDayOfYear;
    int iCountMonth;
    int iDayOfMonth;

    for (iDayOfYear = 0, iCountMonth = 0; iCountMonth < sizeof(countMonths)/sizeof(countMonths[0]); iCountMonth++)
        for (iDayOfMonth = 0; iDayOfMonth < countMonths[iCountMonth]; iDayOfMonth++)
        {
            assert(iDayOfYear < sizeof(month)/sizeof(month[0]));
            month[iDayOfYear++] = iCountMonth+1;
        }           
    assert(iDayOfYear == sizeof(month)/sizeof(month[0]));

    for (iDayOfYear = 0, iCountMonth = 0; iCountMonth < sizeof(countMonths)/sizeof(countMonths[0]); iCountMonth++)
        for (iDayOfMonth = 0; iDayOfMonth < countMonths[iCountMonth]; iDayOfMonth++)
        {
            assert(iDayOfYear < sizeof(day)/sizeof(day[0]));
            day[iDayOfYear++] = iDayOfMonth;
        }
    assert(iDayOfYear == sizeof(day)/sizeof(day[0]));
```

The idea is to loop through the months in the year, and for each month loop through the days in the month - but maintain an overall day of the year counter to fill in the `month` and `day` arrays.

I'm using the [C standard library header "assert.h"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h) to ensure I don't overflow my array bounds, and that each array is fully initialized.